# Why is my useEffect function not triggering a redirect?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a simple redirect I want to implement if a route is accessed without a user logged in.

To handle this I just check props for currentUser.id

My console.log("here") is hit, and logged, but the navigate call doesn't fire off

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.currentUser.id)
    if (!props.currentUser.id){
      console.log("here")
      navigate("/")
    }
  }, [props.currentUser.id]);
```

Comment: Are you rendering this component using the `navigate` function within a routing context so it *can* navigate? Where is `navigate` declared? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your code here is too incomplete to understand what the problem might be. For one thing, `navigate()` isn't even defined.

Answer (score -1):

Had to place

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

above my useEffect() call